# How do I modify/extend a javascript function in place by an inject script?

Tags: javascript, xss, bookmarklet

Lets say this function...

```
function foo(param){
// original works
}
```

is already in-place in an html document.

I have a bookmarklet that injects an external script to the document. From that script, I want to modify the behavior of foo() function into this...

```
function foo(param){
// original works
bar(param);
}
```

bar() is a new function in the injected script.
I have no problem duplicating foo in the injected script.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in javascript can be an object, including functions. With this in mind, you can create a duplicate of the old function, then override the new one while referencing the duplicate:

```
function foo(param){
// original works
}

var old_foo = foo;

function foo(param) {
 old_foo(param);
 bar(param);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, I was testing something similar to this and  oops exception: *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* when I ran the new foo. PS: +1.

Comment: @JCOC611 Was it a ... <puts on sunglasses> ...StackOverflow?  YEEEEEaaaaaah!

Comment: would it be more correct to store the return value of old_foo() and return that from the new foo()?, like this: `function foo(param){var ret = old_foo(param);bar(param);return ret;}`

Comment: @david You are correct, although I will keep my answer simple as not to confuse.